# How can I convert varchar to DATE in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column right now as STRING value: ex. 20200101, I want to get this column and change the date format, so: 2020-01-01.

Is there way to do this?

I have tried CAST as and TO_DATE but they don't seem to be working

I would like to go from the left colum to the right column.

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you wrote using TO_DATE and explain in what way it didn’t work

Answer (score 2):

To_DATE with the right pattern should work.

The [manual](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date) does explain it very good

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20200101', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is coming from some varchar column and if the format of your string date is not consistent. Meaning your dataset in that attribute should have one format for all rows. If its uncertain then you can use TRY_TO_DATE function to convert it, it will produce NULL when it does not get the accepted format.

```
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE('21210218', 'YYYYMMDD');
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE('2021-02-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE('2021.02.18', 'YYYY.MM.DD');
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE('2021/02/18', 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```